# Cypress: How to test HTML5 built in validation popup?

Tags: html, validation, testing, cypress, react-hook-form

How can we catch an HTML5 built in popup validation error when testing an App with Cypress? It does not seem to be showing up in the DOM so I have no clue about how to catch it with a `cy` command (I'm using `testing-library`).

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can refer the cypress [FAQ](https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/using-cypress-faq#Can-I-check-that-a-form-s-HTML-form-validation-is-shown-when-an-input-is-invalid) for this.

```
cy.get('locator').then(($input) => {
  expect($input[0].validationMessage).to.eq('Your error message')
})
```